# Pyspark Currency Converter

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, currency

I have a dataframe `df` like this:

```
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+-----+--------+----------+
|price|currency|      date|
+-----+--------+----------+
|   10|     USD|2018-07-03|
|   10|     USD|2018-03-19|
|    8|     SEK|2018-07-10|
|   10|     NOK|2018-05-25|
|    5|     EUR|2018-05-13|
+-----+--------+----------+
```

and I want to convert each `price` to `EUR` and put into column `price_eur`, according to specified `date`.

```
+-----+--------+----------+---------+
|price|currency|      date|price_eur|
+-----+--------+----------+---------+
|   10|     USD|2018-07-03|     8.57|
|   10|     USD|2018-03-18|     8.12|
|    8|     SEK|2018-07-10|     0.78|
|   10|     NOK|2018-05-25|     1.05|
|    5|     EUR|2018-05-13|        5|
+-----+--------+----------+---------+
```

Does anyone know an efficient way of doing so?

While having `pandas` dataframe I can simply use [CurrencyConverter python API](https://pypi.org/project/CurrencyConverter/), I could not find a way to do it in `pyspark`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a udf and use the same API.

```py
from currency_converter import CurrencyConverter
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType

c = CurrencyConverter()
convert_curr = F.udf(lambda x,y : c.convert(x, y, 'EUR'), FloatType())
df = df.withColumn('price_eur', convert_curr('price', 'currency'))
```

EDIT:

Install the python package first using the following command,

```
pip install currencyconverter
```

Comment: Thank you. but I can't make it work: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'currency_converter'`.

Comment: You have to install the api first (I assumed you already did it). Check the edit.

Comment: Yes, and I used it for pandas dataframe. However it seems to be tricky to create `udf` from it, i guess.

Comment: `udf` just gives you the access to every row of dataframe. Inside `udf`, you can use any function, package or library of python in same way as you use it in `pandas`. Is it working now?

Comment: It is working for me. If the error is still `ModuleNotFoundError`, it is a problem with installation. Are you able to import the module in python?

Comment: The package needs to installed on all workers, too. Perhaps that's the issue here.

Comment: It's weird then. It perfectly works in python on pandas dataframes! And of course I can import it in python.

Comment: I have just tried and @mayank agrawal's solution is working perfectly. I didn't get any error

Comment: As @pansen said, it should definitely be the issue of workers then.

Comment: @pansen Yes, that's the issue. But since I am not admin, I can't install on the worker nodes. I'm trying to find a way to do it (for example `spark-submit`). Not successful so far :(